# How to make function from string variables?

Tags: php, html

How to make function from string? I am new to php programming and wanted solution for below code.

If I want to access page for test2.php?page=test for below class:

```
class test{
   public static function getTest(){
      //code here....
   };
}
```

and wanted to access test2.php?page=test using variable so what should I do?

```
require_once "test.php";
$variabe = $_GET['page'];

test::get . ucfirst($variable) . ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php
class test{
   public static function getTest(){
      echo 'getTest()!!';
   }
}

$variable = 'Test';

// since we are interpolating a raw string, input from $_GET, and a function we need to let PHP know to fully complete this string before using it as a function call
test::{"get".ucfirst($variable)}();



// Build the full method name ahead of time and you can just call it using the variable
$variable2 = 'getTest';

test::$variable2();
```

Output:

```
getTest()!!
```

Comment: @manoj03h You're welcome, please consider accepting this as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark just below the up/down vote arrows `:-)`